# Can I make plotly tooltip only register elements in foreground?

Tags: python, plotly, tooltip, stacked-bar-chart

I've created a stacked bar chart which shows an "achieved" metric in the foreground in gray, and a "target" metric in the background in red. The idea is that if we meet our target, the red bar will be hidden entirely; if we do not meet our target, a small sliver of red will show at the top of the bar, indicating how much we fell short. The intended behavior is for the tooltip to reflect the "target" data only if the target bar exceeds the achieved bar so that the tooltip can hover over the "target" bar exclusively.

I have functional tooltips built with plotly express, but curiously the tooltips will occasionally register the "target" bar in the background, even if hovering over the "achieved" bar. I realize that the "target" element exists, but given that the "achieved" element is drawn on top of it, it is strange that the tooltip would not reflect the foremost element.

Is there a way to correct this?

```
# create stacked bar chart  
fig = go.Figure()  

customData = [dfStacked[dfStacked['Variable'] == 'Target']['Variable'],
                dfStacked[dfStacked['Variable'] == 'Achieved']['Variable']]

# add Target bar chart  
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(  
    x=dfStacked[dfStacked['Variable'] == 'Target']['Transport'],  
    y=dfStacked[dfStacked['Variable'] == 'Target']['Value'],
    customdata=customData[0],
    name='Target', 
    marker_color='red',  
    base=0  
))  

# add Achieved bar chart  
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(  
    x=dfStacked[dfStacked['Variable'] == 'Achieved']['Transport'],  
    y=dfStacked[dfStacked['Variable'] == 'Achieved']['Value'],
    customdata=customData[1],
    name='Achieved', 
    marker_color='gray', 
    base=0  
))

fig.update_traces(hovertemplate='%{customdata} = %{y} MPH' + "<extra></extra>")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mak8W.png)

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce your graph because I don't have the data, but I too have experience of hover displays in the background when bar graphs are superimposed. I have not found any correspondence or workaround for this. So why don't you consider changing your thinking and changing the graph to one that stacks up the achieved results and the unachieved values up to the target values?